# how can get only numbers from the input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have on keyup and mask for phone numbers, I need to get only digits, not symbols on mask, but it is not working, please let me know my mistake.

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){
    sd=parseInt(document.getElementById('search').value);
    alert(sd);



'$(window).load(function()
{
   var phones = [{ "mask": "(###) ###-####"}, { "mask": "(###) ###-####"}];
    $('#search').inputmask({ 
        mask: phones, 
        greedy: true, 
        definitions: { '#': { validator: "[0-9]", cardinality: 1}} });
});'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might recommend doing a `replace` with a regular expression to remove all non-digits:

```js
const sd = document.getElementById('search').value.replace(/\D/g,'');
console.log(sd);
```

```html
<input id="search" value="(123) 456 - 7890" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `unmask` method provided by the inputmask library:

```js
const phones = [{ "mask": "(###) ###-####"}, { "mask": "(###) ###-####"}];
const mask = { 
  mask: phones, 
  greedy: true, 
  definitions: { '#': { validator: "[0-9]", cardinality: 1}} 
}

$(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){
  let value = document.getElementById('search').value;
  console.log( Inputmask.unmask( value, mask ) );
});

$('#search').inputmask( mask );
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/kostasx/pen/YzPKmVP?editors=1011)

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can prevent inputs by returning false on the `keydown` event.

```
//48-57 are number keys, 96-105 are numpad keys, the rest are control keys [backspace, tab, enter, left, up , right, down, delete]
$('input').on('keydown', e => (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <=57) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <=105) || [8,9,13,37,38,39,40,46].includes(e.keyCode));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/un18rw96/